# Displays if a whole number (>0) is divisible by 2 and 3

Tags: java, if-statement

I have tried to do this in java however the **&&** symbols keep on giving error.
Below is the code  that I used:

```java
int d = 18;

    {
    if ((d % 2) && (d% 3));
    {
        System.out.println("True!");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("False!");
    }
}
```

This is my code. I am not sure why its not working. Thanks

The error message is **The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int. #**

I have got it to work now. I have an else error . "The error says Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

```java
public class CS1702_Lab3_4 {

    int d = 18;

    {
        if ((d % 2 == 0) && (d % 3 == 0));
        {
            System.out.println("True!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
        }
}
```

Also when I add an else it says **Syntax error on token "else", delete this token**

Comment: "having an error" what error?

Comment: Hint: what is the return value of `(d % 2)`?

Comment: You are also missing an `else`

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please check my edit . Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want a semicolon on the end of the if statement?

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: isn't saying `divisible by 2 and divisible by 3` the same as saying it is divisible by 6? Or did you mean `divisible by 2 or divisible by 3`?

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about the modulus operator, and how to [check divisibility in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260690/how-to-check-if-number-is-divisible-by-a-certain-number).

```
if ((d % 2 == 0) && (d % 3 == 0))
{
    System.out.println("True!");
}
```

Also, you had a rogue semi-colon at the end of your if statement.

EDIT: Fixed code

```
public class CS1702_Lab3_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Entry into our program
        int d = 18;

        if ((d % 2 == 0) && (d % 3 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("Divisible!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not divisible!");
        }
    }

}
```

I'd recommend looking at some basic Java tutorials, however the fixes I applied included:

- Contained your code inside of a method, specifically the main method, which is the entry point to a runnable Java application. Java is not a procedural language, code outside of variable, method, class, package and import declarations need to be contained inside of a method
- Fixed syntax on your if statement, removed rogue semi colon

Comment: If this doesn't work can you post your full method declaration and body so I can understand what else could be causing the syntax error

Comment: Thanks. This worked .  I have a persistent error when inserting else. the error is "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @1918490 can you please add the full method declaration and body to your original post

Comment: @1918490 the syntax you are trying to use is not valid Java syntax, I'll make an edit to my post with corrected code. I'd recommend doing some basic Java tutorials to get a grasp of the Java syntax as I presume you are coming from a different language.

Comment: @1918490 Please see my edits and let me know how you get on, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. `if ((d % 2) && (d% 3));` you have a semicolon `;` at the end,
   remove it.
2. If `d == 18`, then `((d%2) && (d%3)) = (0 && 0) = 0` So in this
   case, What java sees is: `if(0){ // ... }`

If I remember correctly, this is valid in C/C++, but not in Java. That is why you get error.

Anyways, to fix the problem, you can do this:

```
if (((d % 2) == 0) && ((d % 3) == 0)){
     System.out.println("Divisible!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not divisible!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` condition expects boolean. `Mod` operation would not return boolean, this is why compiler is intelligent and gives you this error.

if you try to run

```
 if (1 && 2) // this will give you an error as well.
```

The expressions need to evaluate to  a boolean (either true or false) in order to understand operators like && and ||

Moreover, you statement will not work since you are using `;` at the end.